# avoiding to duplicate listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclicklistener

I need to set focus on input and textarea elements of a sortable list.
Here is my code (1).

a) When I load the list it works fine because it adds a listener for each input.
b) When I add a new element to the list it duplicates the listeners.

How should avoid this?
Maybe trying to use a single listener on body using event delegation?
Any ideas?
thanks

(1)

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var setFocus = function () {
        $('.ui-sortable').find('input, textarea').click(function () {
            $(this).focus();
        });
    };
    $('.ui-sortable').on('DOMNodeInserted', setFocus);
    setFocus();
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('body').on('.ui-sortable input, .ui-sortable textarea', 'click', function () {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it and add it again

```
$('.ui-sortable').off('DOMNodeInserted').on('DOMNodeInserted', setFocus);
```

You can try adding it like this

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.ui-sortable', setFocus);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either modify your code to only add the listener once, or remove the old listener first:

```
$('.ui-sortable').off('DOMNodeInserted').on('DOMNodeInserted', setFocus);
```

If you have other listeners you don't want to remove, you can use the namespace feature when you add the listener, so that you can only remove the listener you're interested in:

```
$('.ui-sortable').off('DOMNodeInserted.setFocus').on('DOMNodeInserted.setFocus', setFocus);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try delegating the event .. So that you do not need to assign the event every single time you create a new element

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.ui-sortable', setFocus);
```

Comment: Don't you want to use `off`, not `unbind`? Or at least pass something to `unbind`?

Comment: Not passing will remove all the events associated to it.. We can pass a specific event if we want .. DOMNodeInserted in this case .. Edited the post